# Drawing with transparent texture, then opaque color

Tags: java, opengl

I initialize OpenGL like so to make transparent textures transparent:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I draw my texture like this:

```
glPushMatrix();
    //translate
    //neutralize colors
    //bind texture
    //vertex points
glPopMatrix();
```

But when I try to draw a quad immediately afterwards, it won't show up:

```
glPushMatrix();
{
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {           
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(10, 0);
        glVertex2f(10, 10);
        glVertex2f(0, 10);
    }
    glEnd();
}
glPopMatrix();
```

If I remove the initialization above, the quad appears, but then my texture is no longer transparent.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Should I call `glDisable(GL_BLEND);` whenever I want to draw something that is not a texture?

Comment: You should call `glDisable(GL_BLEND)` if you want to disable blending. However, `glColor3` sets the alpha value to 1 implicitely, so it's not clear why your code doesn't work. Are you doing anything else inbetween? Maybe you could post the code for drawing the textured objects.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable blending before drawing your quad.

EDIT: Can you post more code? The problem may be somewhere else, for example if you have not disabled the texture before drawing the quads.

Answer (score -1):

There's **no** need to disable blending when drawing.

I call `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)` when I need to draw transparent cubes (with texture).

I usually disable DEPTH test upon drawing with blend mode enabled:

```
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);                // Turn Blending On
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);          // Turn Depth Testing Off
```

**NeHe** has a nice tutorial on [blending](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/blending/16001/).

Comment: he doesn't state if he wants the quad to be transparent. If not, you can save fillrate disabling blending. If he wants both to be transparent, your option is fine :)

Comment: I assumed that the texture he mentioned was being applied to what was being draw.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same but he is not passing texture coordinates, so probably is defaulting to (0,0) and there the texture may have alpha=0.0 I think he needs to give more information on what he is trying to archive so that we don't need to guess too much ;)